# Какая временная сложность поиска в std::hash_set?

Tags: c++

Какая временная сложность поиска в std::hash_set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Время поиска всегда константное.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что set:has_set работает со скоростью O(1)???

Comment: Блин, асимптотически — да. Не надо путать реальную производительность вот в данном запросе с асимптотической амортизированной оценкой. Все оценки на скорость работы хэшмап и ко делаются исключительно амортизационным анализом.

Comment: В смысле, делаются-то они как душе угодно, но единица получается только амортизационным анализом.

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от выбора хеш функции. 
При "плохом" выборе хеш функции сложность возрастает до n (чтобы это понять, смотри поведение hash_set в случае коллизий). 
В случае использования "хорошей" хеш функции сложность 1.

Comment: Я бы сказал, в случае использования идеальной функции и идеальных данных. На практике такое обычно не случается.